# What is the average lifespan of a Gree?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

While researching the old races of the Star Wars galaxy, I did not find any information on the longevity of the vast majority of these. Certainly, we see vestiges of their past exploits in the LORE but no information relating to their own species (except for a banal physical description).

In light of the technological prowess of the [Gree species](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gree_(species)/Legends) as well as its historical longevity (an extremely old breed but still present during the reign of Sheev Palpatine), do we know the average lifespan of a Gree?